# Vue js - is that right to put all my code in watch?

Tags: vue.js

I Have component A and Component B
in component A i have an API call.

when i passing info to my component b:

```
<B :structuresMetaData="structureTree"></B>
```

Inside mounted the variable structuresMetaData the length is 0

and inside the watch the length is 1.

my issue that mounted appear before the watch.

is it would be right to put all my code in watch ? if not what is the solution ?

Comment: Try to make the API call inside the `create()`

Comment: Also what is the relationship between A and B? Which one is parent/children? Please provide something like codesandbox.io demo so we can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `structureTree` is being changed *after* `<B>` is created/mounted.

You have two options depending on your use case:

The first option is to defer the creation of `<B>` until your data is loaded. This way you don't need `<B>` to watch for changes to the prop and the prop will be fully populated in the created/mounted hook. This is the simpler approach.

Assuming `structureTree` is initially an empty array:

```html
<B
  v-if="structureTree.length > 0"
  :structuresMetaData="structureTree"
/>
```

```js
created() {
  // this.structuresMetaData is a non-empty array here
}
```

I usually initialize my data with `null` so that I can distinguish between "not loaded" and "loaded" (where "loaded" can actually be an empty array if the data I fetched from the API was empty).

The second way is using a watcher in `<B>` to react to changes to the prop. You will need to do this method if the bound prop might change multiple times and you need `<B>` to update in some way to that change.

```js
watch: {
  structuresMetaData(value) {
    // React to the change, load secondary data, etc
  }
}
```

What exactly are you doing in `<B>` that requires a watcher? It's best to avoid explicit watchers if you can avoid them because it usually means you are copying data around and it gets messy when you don't have a [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth). Use pure computed properties whenever you can if you just want to transform the data in some way.